# Create form elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form where a user is able to fill his full name in inputs. I've created a simple form, but the form shows only first name input. I'm thinking about forEach method to fulfill the task, but don't correctly understand how to make it. Or should I look into another way? I've also thought about creating 'second-name' and 'third-name' elements but this way doesn't fit me.
Thanks

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector('.name');
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const lists = document.querySelector('.lists')

function addName(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = nameInput.value;
    lists.appendChild(listItem);
    nameInput.value = '';
}

button.addEventListener('click', addName);
```

```html
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Имя">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Фамилия">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Отчество">
        <button type="submit" class="button">ОК</button>
    </form>
    <div class="block">
        <ul class="lists"></ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the names from the form and make a list item of them every time the button is pressed, you can use `querySelectorAll` to select all the name inputs and loop through them to get the names.

```js
const nameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const lists = document.querySelector('.lists')

function addName(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    var names = []
    nameInputs.forEach(i =>{
      names.push(i.value);
      i.value = '';
    });
    listItem.textContent = names.join(' ');
    lists.appendChild(listItem);
}

button.addEventListener('click', addName);
```

```html
<form class="form">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Имя">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Фамилия">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Отчество">
        <button type="submit" class="button">ОК</button>
    </form>
    <div class="block">
        <ul class="lists"></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer perfectly fits

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to always use `name` attribute for your form elements. So that you can identify them.

Simply add `name` to your inputs and give an `id` to your form.

```
  const nameInput = document.querySelector('.name');
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const lists = document.querySelector('.lists')



function addName(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const contact_form = document.getElementById("contact_form");
    
    Array.from(contact_form.elements).forEach((input) => {
         if(input.type === 'text') {
          const listItem = document.createElement('li');
          listItem.textContent = `${input.name} = ${input.value}`;
          lists.appendChild(listItem);
          input.value = '';
         }
    });
}

button.addEventListener('click', addName);




 <form id="contact_form" class="form">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="name" placeholder="Имя">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" class="name" placeholder="Фамилия">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="name" placeholder="Отчество">
        <button type="submit" class="button">ОК</button>
    </form>
    <div class="block">
        <ul class="lists"></ul>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rjv32dzt/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this way. Very usefull